# Java: PropertyChangeListener for JTextArea No response?

Tags: java, swing, listener, jtextarea, propertychangelistener

I use `PropertyChangeListener` for `JTextFields` to listen for **value** change, and it works normally, and when I use it with `JTextArea`; no errors in the code and it is compiled normally. However this method shows response when some change occur in a `JTextField` text value but no response when it comes to `JTextArea`.

This is how I wrote the code

Inside the constructor:

```
textField_1.addPropertyChangeListener("value", new ChangeListener());
textField_2.addPropertyChangeListener("value", new ChangeListener());
textArea.addPropertyChangeListener("value", new ChangeListener());
```

And somewhere inside the class:

```
private class ChangeListener implements PropertyChangeListener
{
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e)
    {
        Object source = e.getSource();

        if ((source == textField_1) || (source == textField_2) || (source == textArea))
        {
              System.out.println("some value changed "+ source.getClass());
        }
    }
}
```

I use *new value* each time I make a change to these compomemts text value.

THanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- use [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for listening of changes in [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)
- from this [Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/eventsandcomponents.html) you can to fire a new event to [PropertyChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html)
- fire a new event to `PropertyChangeListener` only in the case thats required, no idea from this description, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Thanks; DocumentListener is perfect

Comment: Thanks; `DocumentListener` is perfect. But I am wondering; Since there is no error in my code and the line  that adds `PropertyChangeListener` to `JTextArea` compiled, why not respond?. I replace it with `DocumentListener` it now works. **Anyway Thanks; your answer is perfect.**

Comment: glad if help you, only the Document is responsible for listening all changes from/to JTextComponent,